# PCA 9685 i2c communication issue

Tags: linux, i2c, python-3, raspberry-pi-os

I would like to ask a question regarding the usage of secondary channel of i2c in rpi 4b.
I have enabled the secondary channel through adding "dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=2,i2c_gpio_sda=22,i2c_gpio_scl=23" in the "config.txt" file. Thus, I was able to attain the address "0x40" by typing in "i2cdetect -y 2" in the terminal of my rapsberry pi 4b. However when I run my python code, it states an error which "no i2c device found at address 0x40." I tried to debug the program and it is the problem with the "busio" module. The strange thing is that when I connect it to the primary i2c channel, it works, however, if I connect it to my secondary channel the program doesn't work. It would be so much appreciated if anyone can help me solving up this issue.

My code was:

```
    import time
    import board
    import busio
    from adafruit_pca9685 import PCA9685
    from adafruit_motor import servo

    i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
    pca = PCA9685(i2c, address=0x40)
    pca.frequency = 50

    servo_motor = servo.Servo(pca.channels[0])

    while True:
       servo_motor.angle = 0
       time.sleep(1)
       servo_motor.angle = 90
       time.sleep(1)
       servo_motor.angle = 180
       time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: what is the question that you would like to ask? ... please format your code ... click the `Edit` button

Comment: Please provide  clear photos of the connections.