# Python code cannot detect my i2c address

Tags: python, pi-4, linux, i2c, electronics

I would like to ask some opinions regarding i2c communications with pca9685. My i2c1(SDA=GPIO2, SCL=GPIO3) of my rpi 4b is used by my mpu6050, which I had to enable one more i2c channel of my raspberry pi. So, I enabled it through the figure below:[image]

I rebooted my rpi 4b after, then successfully detected the address through i2cdetect.
[image]

I went through to test the device writing some codes, and the giving me some errors which said "ValueError: No I2C device at address: 0x40"

The strange thing is that when I connect pca9685 through the i2c1(SDA=GPIO2, SCL=GPIO3), it works.

My code was:

```
    import time
    import board
    import busio
    from adafruit_pca9685 import PCA9685
    from adafruit_motor import servo

    i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
    pca = PCA9685(i2c, address = 0x40) 
    pca.frequency = 50

    servo_m = servo.ContinuousServo(pca.channels[0])
    
    servo_m.throttle = -1
    time.sleep(1)
    servo_m.throttle = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    servo_m.throttle = 1
    time.sleep(1)
    servo_m.throttle = 0
    time.sleep(1)
```

I will post the specific error for a better visualization. Moreover, I will post the picture regarding the configurations of the pins (Black - GND, Orange = SCL, Green = SDA, Red  = Vcc, White = V+). Thanks!

[image: Black - GND, Orange = SCL, Green = SDA, Red = Vcc, White = V+]
The followings are the error I got:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Eile "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit bus 
    device/i2c device.py", line 176, in _ probe for device
    Self.i2c.writeto(self.device address, b"")
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/busio.py", line 
    175, in writeto
    return self. _i2c.writeto(address, buffer, stop=stop)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit 
    blinka/microcontroller/generic linux/i2c.py", line 52, in 
    writeto
    self. _i2c_bus.write_bytes(address, buffer[start:end])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Adafruit 
    PureI0/smbus.py", ling 320, in write bytes
    self. _device.write(buf)
    OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

    During handling of the above exception, another exception 
    occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit bus 
    device/i2c_device.py", line 182, in _ probe for device
    self.i2c.readfrom_into(self.device address, result)
    Eile "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/busio.py", line 
    165, in readfrom_into
    return self. _i2c.readfrom_into(address, buffer, stop=stop)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit 
    blinka/microcontroller/generic linux/i2c.py", line 59, in 
    readfrom into
    readin = self. _i2c_bus.read_bytes(address, end - start)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Adafruit 
    PureIO/smbus.py", line 187, in read bytes
    return self._device.read (number)
    OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

    During handling of the above exception, another exception 
    occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Eile "/home/bob/FYP/Servo/test110.py", line 13, in <module>
    pca = PCA9685(i2c, address=0x40)
    Eile "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit 
    pca9685.py", line 141, in _ init
    self.i2c_device = i2c_device.I2CDevice(i2c_bus, address)
    Eile “/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit bus 
    device/i2c_device.py", line 63, in _ init
    self.__probe_for_device()
    Eile "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit bus 
    device/i2c_device.py", line 185, in __ probe for device
    raise ValueError("No I2C device at address: Ox%x" % 
    self.device_address)
    ValueError: No I2C device at address: 0x40
```

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post TEXT

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is in effect a duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/142543/pca-9685-i2c-communication-issue

Comment: @joan dude its the same person, I have written that question without user info which it was hard to edit the question for me. So, I've chose to rewrite my question with pictures.

Comment: I understand that.  However this is the same question.  You should have supplied the information already requested rather than writing another variation on the question.

Comment: I see. I will do so, it will be very much appreciated if you can help! Thanks

Comment: You do not appear to understand I²C which is a bus. It allows multiple devices (provided they have discrete addresses). You don't NEED multiple I²C devices. You have used the (frankly unusual) Adafruit code rather than normal BCM numbering; `board.SCL` is almost certainly Adafruit for `SCL1`

Comment: @Milliways Thank you for the help. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Not unless you post legible text and more complete detail of what you are connecting (including links to devices). I am not going to attempt to comment on Adafruit code (which I find inscrutable). I suggest you either connect your device to pins 2,3 or modify the code to use I²C-4. Your post indicates a connected device, it is your code is trying to read something else.

Comment: @Milliways Yeah, when I try to debug, the part which makes the error is the busio.I2c(), which is indeed an adafruit code. How should I edit it to use I2C-4. Sorry I am very new to this rpi. By the way, pins 2, 3 are used for communicating with my sensor. That's why I needed another channel for me to communicate with my motor driver, pca9685. I thought it was troublesome to connect both, sensor and driver, on the same pin.

Comment: If you can't join 2 wires together - many use a breadboard (at least for prototyping) debugging Adafruit code is a couple of orders of magnitude more complex. I run half a dozen I²C devices connected to pins 3,5. If you REALLY want to persist with your existing code I suggest using real BCM numbers instead of Adafruit symbolic constants such as `board.SCL`

Answer (score 0):

The I2C bus requires pull-ups to 3V3 on the SDA and SCL pins.

GPIO 2 (SDA) and GPIO 3 (SCL) have hard-wired 1k8 ohm resistors fitted on the Pi board.

If you use different GPIO for the I2C bus you will need to add external resistors for the required pull-ups.